# Extending/overriding Django TestCase class

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, django-testing

My application has three levels of access (i.e. User, Manager, Admin). In my unit tests I have something like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class DocumentViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
         # Create 3 users

    def test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
         self.client.login(username='manager', password='xx')
         resp = self.client.get(reverse('view_upload'))
         self.assertEqual(str(resp.context['user']), 'manager')
```

Testing all three levels could be defined by the same routine:

1. login user
2. post/get to some url
3. create assertions to check the post/get response

I wanted to encapsulate all the steps in some wrapper class or extend the `TestCase`, so that redundancy is avoided. I was thinking about something like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class DocumentViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
         # Create 3 users

    def test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
         self.client.login(username=['manager','admin','simple_user'], password=['xx','x','xxx'])
         resp_manager, resp_admin, resp_simple_user = self.client.get(reverse('view_upload'))
         self.assertEqual(str(resp_manager.context['user']), 'manager')
         self.assertEqual(str(resp_admin.context['user']), 'admin')
         self.assertEqual(str(resp.resp_simple_user['user']), 'simple_user')
```

Does anyone have suggestions how I could override get/post/login methods? Would creating a wrapper class around `TestCase` be easier? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I achieved the above behaviour, maybe it will be useful to someone:

```
from django.test.client import Client


class LoginDetails:
    def __init__(self, login_fn, **credentials):
        self._users = [dict(username=name, password=password) for name, password in
                       zip(credentials.get('username'), credentials.get('password'))]
        self._login_fn = login_fn

    def get_login(self):
        for user in self._users:
            yield self._login_fn(**user)


class ClientExtended(Client):
    def login(self, **credentials):
        if isinstance(credentials.get('username'), list):
            return LoginDetails(super(ClientExtended, self).login, **credentials)
        else:
            return super(ClientExtended, self).login(**credentials)

    def get(self, path, *args, **extra):
        if extra.get('login_list'):
            login_list = extra.pop('login_list', None)
            responses = []
            for _ in login_list.get_login():
                responses.append(super(ClientExtended, self).get(path, *args, **extra))
                super(ClientExtended, self).logout()
            return responses
        else:
            return super(ClientExtended, self).get(path, *args, **extra)

    def post(self, path, *args, **extra):
        if extra.get('login_list'):
            login_list = extra.pop('login_list', None)
            responses = []
            for _ in login_list.get_login():
                responses.append(super(ClientExtended, self).post(path, *args, **extra))
                super(ClientExtended, self).logout()
            return responses
        else:
            return super(ClientExtended, self).post(path, *args, **extra)
```

My test looks like this now:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from xx import ClientExtended


class DocumentViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
         self.client = ClientExtended()
         # Create 3 users

    def test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
         logins = self.client.login(username=['manager','admin','simple_user'], password=['xx','x','xxx'])
         resp_manager, resp_admin, resp_simple_user = self.client.get(reverse('view_upload'), login_list=logins)
         self.assertEqual(str(resp_manager.context['user']), 'manager')
         self.assertEqual(str(resp_admin.context['user']), 'admin')
         self.assertEqual(str(resp.resp_simple_user['user']), 'simple_user')
```